# Phonegap Bonjour/Zeroconf or Websocket IP Discovery from HTML5

Tags: html, cordova, bonjour, zeroconf

I am trying to implement a Phonegap (HTML5) application which connects to a Websocket server (running in an embedded device, also has Bonjour service) to exchange data within home network.

I would like to know the best possible way of detecting the server IP using Phonegap. I have explored and found that Titanium and Quickconnect support Bonjour. But I would like to stick to Phonegap for various other reasons.

Any alternative way of detecting the server IP within the local network is also okay.

Need your suggestion.

Comment: I have yet to find a PhoneGap iOS binding to Bonjour discovery protocols, but I did confirm that it is available on the platform.  There is a working sample in the Apple iOS developer library called BonjourWeb.  The challenge will be finding libraries to support Android and the other platforms.

Answer (score 3):

There are two iOS Bonjour plugin implementations for Phonegap (Cordova) on Github:

- https://github.com/jarnoh/cordova-dnssd
- https://github.com/SayGoSolutions/Cordova-BonjourBrowserProxy

Unfortunately I haven't found a cross-platform implementation.

Comment: here is one for Android 
https://github.com/pankajkainthla/phonegap-plugins-all/tree/master/Android/ZeroConf