# phonegap passing info cross app possible?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, cordova

hi first of all sorry about my bad english, heres mi problem:

im developing a mobile app to be deployed with phonegap that means that im coding with javascript/html/css, my app consist on writing a exam giving the correct answers so the app gives it back to you randomly so you can answer it just like any other pc examinations, the thing is that i wanna implement it on a local network so anyone can share exams with anyone connected to the same local network it is that possible? and how can i do it cross platform windows phone 8/ios/android ?

Comment: Read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28138573/mobile-phonegap-applications-on-a-local-network

Comment: they dont answer my question on how to make connection between mobile.   exp. mobile <=> mobile.